# If конструкция в цикле for

Tags: javascript

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML =
            document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML +
            '<li><a href="http://twitter.com/{TwitterUsername}/status/' + (data[i].id_str ? data[i].id_str : data[i].id) + '">' + data[i].text + '</a></li>';
        }
```

Есть вот такой код. Который показывает последние 3 записи в массиве, а когда записей 1-2
то ничего не выводиться, а хром пишет "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_str' of undefined".

Прочитал доки по for, но так и не понял что к чему. Так что буду очень признателен если поможете разобраться, нужно выводить надписи если их меньше 3, и чтоб дебагер угомонился.

Comment: еще неплохо было бы document.getElementById("tweets") вынести выше цикла, записать в переменную и внутри цикла использовать её, чтобы каждый раз не напрягать интерпретатор

Comment: > показывает последние 3 записи в массиве

Он, вроде, первые 3 показывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@YooviPoint](/users/19818/yoovipoint), такой вариант:

```
var cnt = data.length < 3 ? data.length : 3;
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
   // ... дальше без изменений
```

Comment: Огромное, человеческое спасибо =)